# format an array result query from doctrine to a simple array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I have this controller with a doctrine query:

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


$queryIndex = $em->createQuery( 'SELECT g.index
                                    FROM MySpaceMyBundle:Graphique g');

$result = $queryIndex->getScalarResult();

$resultArray = $result -> toArray();

$response = new Response();
$data = json_encode($resultArray);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$response->setContent($data);

return $response;
```

But I have this error:

> Error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object 500
>   Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException

But if I try this in my controller, it works:
        $array = array(1,5,7,85,74,24,9,6,5,4,8555);

```
    $response = new Response();
    $data = json_encode($array);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->setContent($data);

    return $response;
```

it returns me: `[1,5,7,85,74,24,9,6,5,4,8555]`

I need to render my query results into array only to pass the data values into json for Highcharts.

---

**UPDATE**

If I go on the page to watch json resultS (see the controlelr below), with my queries I have this result:

```
[{"index":"1700.000"},{"index":"1200.000"},{"index":"1200.000"},{"index":"1304.000"},{"index":"1800.000"},{"index":"2012.000"},{"index":"2048.000"},{"index":"1048.000"},{"index":"3000.000"},{"index":"5421.000"}]
```

*index* is the name of the column in my database and the *numbers* are the *values* for index in my database.

If I make a `var_dump`, this is the results:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=10)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
      'index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1700.000'</font> <i>(length=8)</i>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
      'index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1200.000'</font> <i>(length=8)</i>
  2 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
      'index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1200.000'</font> <i>(length=8)</i>
  3 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
      'index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1304.000'</font> <i>(length=8)</i>
  4 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
      'index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1800.000'</font> <i>(length=8)</i>
  5 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
      'index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2012.000'</font> <i>(length=8)</i>
  6 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
      'index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2048.000'</font> <i>(length=8)</i>
  7 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
      'index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1048.000'</font> <i>(length=8)</i>
  8 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
      'index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'3000.000'</font> <i>(length=8)</i>
  9 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
      'index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'5421.000'</font> <i>(length=8)</i>
</pre>
```

Like I said, the results are made in order to be in a graphic from `highchart.js`. This is the script in my view:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'linechart',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    var url =  "{{ path('myPage') }}";
    $.getJSON(url,  function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

The highchart to have a simple array to display results in graphics, because when I use the following code for test in my controller, results are displaying correctly:

```
 $array = array(1,5,7,85,74,24,9,6,5,4,8555);
 $response = new Response();
 $data = json_encode($array);
 $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 $response->setContent($data);

 return $response;
```

it returns me:

```
/*var_dump*/
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=11)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>1</font>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>5</font>
  2 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>7</font>
  3 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>85</font>
  4 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>74</font>
  5 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>24</font>
  6 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>9</font>
  7 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>6</font>
  8 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>5</font>
  9 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>4</font>
  10 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>8555</font>
</pre>

/*json response*/
[1,5,7,85,74,24,9,6,5,4,8555]
```

Instead of

```
[{"index":"1700.000"},{"index":"1200.000"},{"index":"1200.000"},{"index":"1304.000"},{"index":"1800.000"},{"index":"2012.000"},{"index":"2048.000"},{"index":"1048.000"},{"index":"3000.000"},{"index":"5421.000"}]
```

I think I need to make the results form my database like this:

```
[1700.000, 1200.000,1200.000,1304.000,1800.000,2012.000,2048.000,1048.000,3000.000,5421.000]
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the problem is with data. In fact I see two problems: `index` means nothing to Highcharts. There should be `y`. Also your values are strings, while should be numbers.

Or, I think simple preprocessing will be enough:

```
$.getJSON(url,  function(data) {
    var d = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, e) {
         d.push(parseFloat(e.index)); // create format [y_0, y_1, ... ,y_N]
    });
    options.series[0].data = d;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you suggested me. Indeed, I need to return an array with integer, not strings with double quotes in an array!. In fact, my values in database for index are decimals not integer.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that you can change format in your backend from `[  {"index": "value"} ]` to `[ {"y": value } ]`. Or use above parser.

Comment: Fus, thank you for reply, of course I keep your suggestion for y values and highccharts properties. You show me another problem in my code that I need to fix.

Comment: Yes, that's just a suggestion. If you prefer your format, use snippet above to get working with "index" format.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

`Query#getScalarResult(): Retrieves a flat/rectangular result set of scalar values that can contain duplicate data. The pure/mixed distinction does not apply.`

Your `$result` variable is probably not an object. Run a `var_dump` on it to verify. This is probably why you can't call `->toArray()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a soltion thanks to stackoverflow developper: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027309/make-a-doctrine-query-result-into-a-simple-json-array?noredirect=1#comment48173361_30027309) !

In fact I need to use a second parameter on my json encode like this to remove the double quote:

```
$data = json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

A great thank to @Dawid Sajdak for his answer. The problem was that I have strings in array, or the values in my database are decimal type.