# Making a Doctrine query results with a simple JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, doctrine-orm

In my database I have an entity named Graphique. This the schema for:

```
class Graphique
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var decimal
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="index", type="decimal", precision=9, scale=3, nullable=false)
     */
    private $index;

    /**
     * @var datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /*getters and setters*/
```

This is some values for index, according to my database schema (example):

```
----------------------------------
id    | index    | dateTime      |
----------------------------------
1     | 1700.000 | dateTime datas|
----------------------------------
2     | 1200.000 | dateTime datas|
----------------------------------
3     | 1200.000 | dateTime datas|
----------------------------------
4     | 1304.000 | dateTime datas|
----------------------------------
etc...| etc...   | etc...        |
```

I have this method into a controller:

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


$queryIndex = $em->createQuery( 'SELECT g.index
                                    FROM MySpaceMyBundle:Graphique g');

$array = array_map('current', $queryIndex);

$response = new Response();
$data = json_encode($array);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$response->setContent($data);

return $response;
```

it returns me this into my json response:

```
["1700.000","1200.000","1200.000","1304.000","1800.000","2012.000","2048.000","1048.000","3000.000","5421.000"]
```

but I need to have this simple array result (instead the json response I give you just above):

```
[1700.000,1200.000,1200.000,1304.000,1800.000,2012.000,2048.000,1048.000,3000.000,5421.000]
```

I need to return a simple array in my json response in order to have this decimal values for displaying them into a highchart graphic.

How can I proceed? I already try some Doctrine methods like `->getArrayresult()`, `->getScalarResult()`, `->toArray()`, but the results are the same. I need to make my query result to a simple array.

Comment: json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); try this one.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, for 'current', is the same thing as ` array_map(function($value) { return $value['index']; }, $resultIndex);`

Comment: @DawidSajdak, please make an answer, your solution is the good one, you're the best. That's what I need to have my values without the double quotes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

This solution should help you.